# Can docker run additional libraries my OS doesnt support?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker

I have an OS(Amazon Linux) that doesn't support a library (libcgj). If I host the application via docker container, can I use this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your application's base images is one of those OSs that support your library, I think you should be fine. However, if you could give some more information like what application, Dockerfile etc. and your specific problem, somebody might answer better your question.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I'm currently learning how Docker works now.
The application is PDFtk, it needs the libcgj library which is no longer supported by many new OS (Centos 7 and Amazon linux)

Comment: In that case, as I mentioned you should build your docker images from (`FROM` instruction at the top of the Dockerfile) one of those OSs the support this library.

Comment: I want to clarify: When building my Docker image I should base it off an OS that is compatible with the libcgj library correct?

Comment: That's right. Once you built the image, you can run that image in any OS.